# Vibrational modes of a black hole's event horizon

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, vibrations, normal-modes

I understand that it is possible for the event horizon of a black hole to support damped modes of vibration called quasi-normal modes, in which it oscillates between spherical and and various oblate shapes. I also understand that if we ignore shrinkage due to Hawking radiation, the area of the black hole's event horizon can never decrease. Does this mean that as the event horizon of a black hole oscillates, its surface area is constrained to remain constant (or at least non-decreasing) while it is oscillating?

Comment: While it seems reasonable to assume that additional energy causing oscillations would increase the surface area, it's difficult to see why we must ignore the Hawking Radiation as part of the overall dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is where action/reaction simply applies.
Get a balloon and make an event horizon and play with it for awhile.

Comment: I think not, but thanks anyway for your response.